# Where can I find state borders for Germany?

Tags: data, borders, germany

I'm looking for free state border layers for Germany. Are there any free sources for such data?

Comment: Do not forget to check the [Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [github.com/isellsoap/deutschlandGeoJSON](https://github.com/isellsoap/deutschlandGeoJSON) has geojson for Deutschland, Bundeslaender, Regierungsbezirke and Kreise, at 4 different resolutions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can download free state border layers of Germany from [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) by selecting `Administrative areas` as the subject.

Answer (score 9):

At http://www.geodatenzentrum.de/ you will find boundarys from the local community up to the national border.

Comment: As far as I know there is NO national border available as simple data set. Instead you have to dissolve from smaller admins yourself. Please link to the specific data set if this is wrong.

Comment: http://www.geodatenzentrum.de/geodaten/gdz_rahmen.gdz_div?gdz_spr=deu&gdz_akt_zeile=5&gdz_anz_zeile=1&gdz_unt_zeile=16&gdz_user_id=0 includes a shapefile VG1000_STA with national borders only.

Comment: I've found out, that this is a really good package, due to high resolution and many addition information: https://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/digitale-geodaten/verwaltungsgebiete/verwaltungsgebiete-1-250-000-stand-01-01-vg250-01-01.html

Answer (score 3):

Natural Earth is a great source for reference boundary data

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can also check this website for Germany data,

http://www.suche-postleitzahl.org/downloads

It is free openstreetmap data.

Answer (score 1):

You can download state borders for Germany from the [GADM data source](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html)

```
 1. level-0 | Country
 2. level-1 | State
 3. level-2 | District
 4. level-3 | Municipality
 5. level-4 | Town
```

License:

> These data were extracted from the GADM database (https://www.gadm.org),
>   version 3.4, April 2018. They can be used for non-commercial purposes
>   only. It is not allowed to redistribute these data, or use them for
>   commercial purposes, without prior consent. See the website
>   (https://www.gadm.org) for more information.

Comment: Is there a dataset available like the gadm in shapefile that I can freely use for any purpose?

Comment: So, GADM data is not sufficient enough for you? Did you try other sources mentioned in this thread ?